# Git - Get Commit back to changes

Tags: git, visual-studio, github

Im using Github and the integrated Git-Control within Visual Studio 2019. I've just made changes to the master branch and pushed them to the repo. My problem is that I made a mistake with that commit. Is there a possibillity to revert those commit AND get those changes I made back to my local changes (non committed).

So not just a simple revert of a commit because I want to modify that commit. To be more specific I want to get this commit not into the master branch, instead the commit should be pushed to another branch and not to the master branch. I can simply revert the commit in the master branch but how can I move it to another branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a possibillity to revert those commit AND get those changes I
> made back to my local changes (non committed).

```
git reset HEAD~

git push -f
```

After that, you should see your's commit as non committed changes and removed from the remote master.

Now you can create a new branch and make a new commit there or you can commit anywhere you want at any branch and make the push to the specified branch (git push origin my_local_branch_name:remote_branch_name)